# Accessing sequential same elements in Watir Ruby

Tags: html, css, ruby, watir

I am trying to access sequential elements and don't know how to advance the the script down the page.  So, here is a snippet of the code.

```
<div class="card highlighted">

<div class="card-fix">
    <a class="card-remove icon" title="Don't show member again" onclick="$jq( '#search-results' ).msg( 'remove', this )" data-userid="93872246">

        X

    </a>
    <dl></dl>
    <div class="card-actions">
        <a class="quickview" title="Quick view" onclick="$jq('#dialog-profile').msg('show', '/profileinfo/SearchProfi…lTseEdmEQ==&lid=1&searchType=S&pageNumber=1'); return false;" href="#"></a>
        <a class="button button-primary" title="Favorite her!" href="/matchbook/addEntry.aspx?uid=Mu/BwYPn0nxhWlTseEdmEQ==&pn=1&rn=4&tp=S&handle=Annie5170&lid=1065"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="card-fix">
    <a class="card-remove icon" title="Don't show member again" onclick="$jq( '#search-results' ).msg( 'remove', this )" data-userid="108272583"></a>
    <dl></dl>
    <div class="card-actions">
        <a class="quickview" title="Quick view" onclick="$jq('#dialog-profile').msg('show', '/profileinfo/SearchProfi…DA3R3daaQ==&lid=1&searchType=S&pageNumber=1'); return false;" href="#"></a>
        <a class="button button-primary" title="Favorite her!" href="/matchbook/addEntry.aspx?uid=y98x/Mj+hc+61DA3R3daaQ==&pn=1&rn=4&tp=S&handle=dancer4498&lid=1065"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In other words I need to continue looping through these quickviews and then running a small script and doing it all again.  Then go to the next page and do it again...etc.  However, if I use this now in a loop it will only pick up the first quickview 5 times.

```
# 5.times do |n|
#   browser.link(:title => 'Quick view').click
#   sleep (2)
#   browser.link(:class => "icon dialog-abandon").click
#   # sleep (2)
# end
```

So my question is how can I have it advance through all of the quick views which there are 18 per page.

**It would also be great to be able to save the 
    `data-user-id="93872246"`
and the portion after the handle in the href, ie.
    `handle=Annie5710`
in a file in a hash as well.**

Thanks and I appreciate all of the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
  //get total title in a page
  totalTitleSize=browser.link(:title => 'Quick view').size
```

and looping it:

```
 totalTitleSize.times do |n|
    browser.link(:title => 'Quick view', :index=> n).click
     sleep (2)
    //test it or use index in it If you need   
    browser.link(:class => "icon dialog-abandon").click
   sleep (2)
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be added to the code.

```
browser.link(:title => 'Quick view', :index=> n).click
```

now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers show, the problem is that the line:

```
browser.link(:title => 'Quick view').click
```

Will always click the first matching link. Using the :index allows you to override the default first match. However, I would argue the better solution is to get a collection of matching links and iterate through that. It will save you from manually handling the index.

```
browser.links(:title => 'Quick view').each do |link|
  link.click
  sleep (2)
  browser.link(:class => "icon dialog-abandon").click
  sleep (2)
end
```

Notice here that we have created a collection using `links` that we iterate though using `each`.

However, since you also want to collect other data, you might want to iterate through the parent divs:

```
browser.divs(:class => 'card-fix').each do |parent_div|
  puts parent_div.link(:class => 'card-remove').data_userid
  #=> "93872246"

  href = parent_div.button(:class => 'button-primary').href
  puts href[/handle=([^&]+)/, 1]
  #=> "Annie5170"

  parent_div.link(:class => "quickview").click
  sleep (2)
  browser.link(:class => "icon dialog-abandon").click
  sleep (2)
end
```